# Does Spring JPA do anything smart with caching entities already retrieved in the current context/request?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

If I have an entity `Product` and an entity `Order` that has a `product` as a field, and while handling a request that is coming in from a Controller, would the result of `Product product = order.getProduct()` be cached throughout the entire call, even though the result of that method call itself is no longer assigned a value? Assume `product` is not modified and could be safely discarded.

i.e. something like:

```
Product product = order.getProduct();
doOtherStuff(order);


void doOtherStuff(Order order) {
    Product product = order.getProduct();
}
```

Does the latter call `order.getProduct()` always/never/usually/sometimes lead to another database call? What are the conditions for that? Assuming a Spring Boot application.

I realize I can see database queries for a line of code but I aim to understand the mechanism behind it.

Comment: Spring Data won't but your underlying JPA provider (probably hibernate) will cache this in the first level cache (the `EntityManager` so it will be retrieved only once).

Comment: Are you using Spring or Spring Boot as the latter keeps the session open by default

Comment: @NicoVanBelle I'm using Spring Boot

Answer (score 0):

You could activate the option to show all the queries that are performed by adding these properties to your `application.properties` file.

```
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE
```

And then you can see whether it performs the query twice or not.

To answer shortly, from my experience, **it does not cache anything**. So it performs the query/call to DB each time you do the call.

You could check caching in Spring Boot:

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cache-tutorial

Comment: True but that would only verify it for that specific scenario, while I aim to understand the mechanism behind it.

Comment: @SebastiaanvandenBroek this is the mechanism as far as I understand it, each time you perform a call, you make a query to the DB. If you want to cache your data, you have to do it "manually".

Comment: Your understanding is wrong. The entity will be cached in the first level cache, the `EntityManager` and only retrieved once. So it will be cached, but not by spring but by your JPA provider.

Comment: @M.Deinum and does that happen implicitly ?

Comment: Yes. It actually depends if a query is isued or not, that depends on your mapping configuration for JPA (could be eager loading, lazy a proxy etc.).

Comment: @M.Deinum can you please give me an article or something to make this clearer?
Thank you.

Comment: Just follow any JPA tutorial (or the specification) which explains this.